# Unsafe assignment of an `any` value Error on form variables (Angular Validators)

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint, angular-custom-validators

I am trying to get my form variables checked by eslint. Unfortunately, in this file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

  public SignUpForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.SignUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      vorname: ['', Validators.required],
      nachname: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      emailbestaetigt: ['', Validators.required],
      passwort: ['', Validators.required],
      passwortbestaetigt: ['', Validators.required],
      Geburtstag: ['', Validators.required],
      Telefonnummer: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  SignUp(): void {
    const mailformat: RegExp = /^\w+([-]?\w+)*@\w+([-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (
      this.SignUpForm.valid &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.vorname.length !== 0 &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.nachname.length !== 0 &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.passwort.length > 7 &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.email.match(mailformat) &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.email === this.SignUpForm.value.emailbestaetigt &&
      this.SignUpForm.value.passwort === this.SignUpForm.value.passwortbestaetigt &&
      this.checkUserAge(this.SignUpForm.value.Geburtstag)
    ) {
      console.log('test');
    } else {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
```

I get these errors from the Linter:

```
34:7   error  Unsafe member access .vorname on an `any` value                         @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
35:7   error  Unsafe member access .nachname on an `any` value                        @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
36:7   error  Unsafe member access .passwort on an `any` value                        @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
37:7   error  Unsafe member access .email on an `any` value                           @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
37:7   error  Unsafe call of an `any` typed value                                     @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
38:7   error  Unsafe member access .email on an `any` value                           @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
38:39  error  Unsafe member access .emailbestaetigt on an `any` value                 @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
39:7   error  Unsafe member access .passwort on an `any` value                        @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
39:42  error  Unsafe member access .passwortbestaetigt on an `any` value              @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
40:25  error  Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `string`  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
40:25  error  Unsafe member access .Geburtstag on an `any` value                      @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

So basically every variable of the if is somehow of type any, and I don't know how to fix this. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular team decided, that `FormGroup.value` is of type `Partial<T>`, in other words, it might or might not contain all of the properties

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

  public SignUpForm = new FormGroup({
    vorname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    nachname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    emailbestaetigt: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    passwort: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    passwortbestaetigt: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    Telefonnummer: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  SignUp(): void {
    const value = this.SignUpForm.getRawValue();
    if (!this.SignUpForm.valid || !value) {
      return; // invalid
    }
    const mailformat: RegExp = /^\w+([-]?\w+)*@\w+([-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (
      value.vorname.length !== 0 &&
      value.nachname.length !== 0 &&
      value.passwort.length > 7 &&
      value.email.match(mailformat) &&
      value.email === value.emailbestaetigt &&
      value.passwort === value.passwortbestaetigt &&
      this.checkUserAge(value.Geburtstag)
    ) {
      console.log('test');
    } else {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
```

---

Yet, you should look into, how custom validators are made and assign them immediately in the constructor. This way, the valid/invalid state would be all that you need to test in order to determine if your form is valid, and your inputs could react to theirs invalid states too.

```js
function RepeatValidator(otherControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const otherControl = (control.parent as FormGroup)?.get(otherControlName);

    if (!otherControl) {
      if (isDevMode()) {
        throw new Error(`RepeatValidator: other control ${otherControlName} not found`);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    if (control.value !== otherControl.value) {
      return { repeat: true };
    }

    return null;
  };
}

const SignUpForm = new FormGroup({
  vorname: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required],
  }),
  nachname: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required],
  }),
  email: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email], // email is Angular defined
  }),
  emailbestaetigt: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required, RepeatValidator('email')],
  }),
  passwort: new FormControl('', {
    passwort: true,
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
  }),
  passwortbestaetigt: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required, RepeatValidator('passwort')],
  }),
  Telefonnummer: new FormControl('', {
    nonNullable: true,
    validators: [Validators.required],
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunetly i still get the same errors

Comment: Did you apply all the changes? Even the way the form is built?

Comment: It works! Thanks man, i love you. You really helped me there